# Why nginx redirect all subdomain to non-www, I just setting redirect www to non-www

Tags: php, redirect, web, nginx

OS:Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Nginx version: 1.6.0

I want redirect www to non-www, but the following config redirect ALL subdomain to non-www.

for example, I visit test.mydomain.com/index.php  also redirect to mydomain.com/index.php

visit ip_address/index.php also redirect to mydomain.com/index.php, test on FF 26 and Chrome 34 but IE11 not redirect.

```
http {
  gzip                on;
  include             mime.types;
  sendfile            on;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;
  keepalive_timeout   65;

  server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    root         /var/www;

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_index   index.php;
      fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
      index        index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  }

  server {
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 http://mydomain.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry my English.I want to only redirect www to non-www. other sub-domain do not redirect.

Comment: try to put `return 301 ...` into `if ($http_host ~* ^www\.mydomain\.com$) {` [here] `}`. I can't see any errors in the config.

Comment: @Deadooshka I am so sorry!! I test on my windows 8.1 laptop,setting the local dns on %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file, it's failed. I tried use curl on Ubuntu vm with /etc/hosts local dns, it's work. I setting the local dns on my Asus RT-N16 router(with AsusWRT Merlin firmware), work on both now. I want add comment,but I can not login yesterday, thx the Chinese GWF!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect is defined in this clause

```
server {
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 http://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

remove the line return 301 http://mydomain.com$request_uri; and that should remove the redirect.

if this is the only site on the server you can remove that whole server block because the root and location for php processing is defined in the server{} block above this one.